# How to retrieve Java Script Array of Objects names

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to retrieve the cars names (i.e. "Ford feigo", "Nissan", "Duster"). And am trying to retrieve them by `carsinfo["0"].name` to get the car names but it gives me **undefined** in return.

```
var carsinfo =    {"cars": [
            {
                "Ford feigo": {
                    "milege": "11",
                    "color": "White",
                    "electric": yes
                }
            },
            {
                "Nissan": {
                    "milege": "33",
                    "color": "Black",
                    "electric": 74
                }
            },
            {
                "Duster": {
                   "milege": "26",
                    "color": "RED",
                    "electric": 87
                }
            }
        ],
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve them with `Object.keys` together with `Array#map`.

```js
let carsinfo = {
  "cars": [{
      "Ford feigo": {
        "milege": "11",
        "color": "White",
        "electric": 'yes'
      }
    },
    {
      "Nissan": {
        "milege": "33",
        "color": "Black",
        "electric": 74
      }
    },
    {
      "Duster": {
        "milege": "26",
        "color": "RED",
        "electric": 87
      }
    }
  ],
};

let cars = [].concat(...carsinfo.cars.map(Object.keys));

console.log(cars);
```

Answer (score 0):

The car names are keys in your object, to get them you could map the surrounding array and then get the key names in a new array where you could access each key based on the index

```js
var carsinfo = {
  "cars": [{
    "Ford feigo": {
      "milege": "11",
      "color": "White",
      "electric": "yes"
    }
  }, {
    "Nissan": {
      "milege": "33",
      "color": "Black",
      "electric": 74
    }
  }, {
    "Duster": {
      "milege": "26",
      "color": "RED",
      "electric": 87
    }
  }],
};

var names = carsinfo.cars.map( k => Object.keys(k).shift());

console.log(names[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a classic approach with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var carsinfo = { cars: [{ "Ford feigo": { milege: "11", color: "White", electric: true } }, { Nissan: { milege: "33", color: "Black", electric: 74 } }, { Duster: { milege: "26", color: "RED", electric: 87 } }] },
    cars = carsinfo.cars.reduce((r, o) => r.concat(Object.keys(o)), []);

console.log(cars);
```

Answer (score 0):

The object carsinfo doesn't have a key called `name`. That is the reason you get `undefined`. You would need to restructure the array and do the following:

```
const cars = Object.values(carsinfo.cars).map((val) => ({ name: Object.keys(val)[0] }));

console.log('name: ', cars[0].name);
```

This isn't a good solution because it is only valid for this particular use case.